# Extracting location data in R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to extract Longitude and Latitude of Hotels location in R. Each [Webpage](https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g304551-d3507485-Reviews-Red_Fox_Hotel_Delhi_Airport-New_Delhi_National_Capital_Territory_of_Delhi.html) has a Google Maps embedded with its locations. I tried various nodes using selector gadget but I am not able to extract the location. I tried using [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721124/scraping-location-data-in-rvest) query as a reference too.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

pg <- read_html("https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g304551-d3507485-Reviews-Red_Fox_Hotel_Delhi_Airport-New_Delhi_National_Capital_Territory_of_Delhi.html")
pg %>% 
html_nodes("#map0Div")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be a way to extract `<script>` nodes. Using your packages

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
```

and getting access by `html_nodes("script")` you can select all elements matching "maps.google" by

```
pg %>%
  html_nodes("script") %>%
  .[str_detect(., "maps\\.google")]
```

and then extract geo locations

```
pg %>%
  html_nodes("script") %>%
  .[str_detect(., "maps\\.google")] %>%
  str_extract_all("[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+")
```

Since there are a lot and I don't know which of them you are looking for it is helpful to take a look at the matching "maps.google" elements

```
pg %>%
  html_nodes("script") %>%
  .[str_detect(., "maps\\.google")] %>%
  str_extract_all("\".*maps\\.google.*\"")
```